# Build a custom layout in single line (2 button + 2 spinner) - Android

Tags: xml, android-layout, user-interface

I'm developing an Android app and I would like build a custom layout about this:

[image]

I'm very confused to align, principally, the buttons and spinners in single line...I don't care for element size (I do this) but I need a simple xml to draw this layout. :)

Can you help me? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The gravity in the root layout takes care of the centering of the textview while the weightSum in the child linear layout makes sure all child widgets of that layout are taking the same space.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="textview" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button2" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `<LinearLayout>` with orientation attribute set to `horizontal` to arrange the 2 buttons and 2 spinners in single line ? :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ......
    >
    <Button ..../>
    <Spinner ..../>
    <Spinner ..../>
    <Button ..../>
</LinearLayout>
```